# Do I have to fully install VS2008 first to then install VS2010 with an upgrade licence key?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I do own a visual studio 2008 professional licence key and a visual studio 2010 professional upgrade key.

My question is: after rebuilding my machine, do I have to install vs2008 first and then install vs2010 or can I skip vs2008 installation and install vs2010 right away.

If I install vs2010 right away, will it ask me for both serial (2008 & 2010) or will it perform a media check (like former 98->XP upgrade) to see that I own a copy of vs2008?

Comment: 99.9% sure it's not going to check for anything. VS 6 was a qualifying upgrade product for VS 2005, and you couldn't even install VS 6 on all the systems that would run VS 2005. I would just try it; you have little to lose.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I'd say that you don't have to install VS2008. And VS2008 key won't be required.
(I'm under an MSDN subscribtion so I don't have to use an upgrade key).

Worse case would be to install vs 2008 after 2010, not a big deal..